# sql datasource in blueprint.xml in servicemix

Tags: sql, datasource, apache-servicemix

```
<bean id="dataSource" class="org.apache.commons.dbcp.BasicDataSource" destroy-method="close">
    <property name="driverClassName" value="com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerDriver"/>
    <property name="url" value="jdbc:sqlserver://localhost:1433/orderdb"/>
    <property name="username" value="abc"/>
    <property name="password" value="pqr"/>
</bean>
```

---

When i try to make connection using dataSource.getConnection()

Not allowing please help

*****Connection Code **********

public class DatabaseBeanH2 {

```
private DataSource dataSource;
private static final Logger LOGGER = LoggerFactory.getLogger(DatabaseBeanH2.class);

public DatabaseBeanH2(){}

public void setDataSource(DataSource dataSource) {
    this.dataSource = dataSource;
}

public void create() throws SQLException{
    Statement sta = dataSource.getConnection().createStatement();
    try {
        sta.executeUpdate("CREATE TABLE orders ( id INT NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY AUTO_INCREMENT, item VARCHAR(50), amount INT, description VARCHAR(300), processed BOOLEAN, consumed BOOLEAN);");
    } catch (SQLException e) {
        LOGGER.info("Table orders already exists");
    }
}

public void destroy() throws SQLException {
    dataSource.getConnection().close();
}
```

}

Comment: Please share the code where you try to get the connection. It is not possible to analyse with the above information.

Comment: you can also check with the jdbc: commands in the servicemix/karaf shell if your datasource is configured correctly.

Answer (score 0):

You have to inject the dataSource bean in your DatabaseBeanH2 in the camel/spring context, something like this:

```
<bean id="databaseBean" class="my.package.DatabaseBeanH2">
    <property name="dataSource" ref="dataSource" />
</bean>
```

Comment: @Vrushali Shinde This question/answer is a duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28757848/sql-connection-in-spring-servicemix-camel, please stay on one topic, it is not necessary nor accepted by the community to ask the same questions multiple times.